# website links messed up // .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I screwed up my .htaccess` file and now my links are messed up.

for example `www.cardler.com/contact.php` changes to `www.cardler.com/awstats/contact.php`

if you manually type in `cardler.com/contact.php` it works...

Link: `www.cardler.com/index.php` - try it out by clicking on the contact button.

```
.htaccess

    RewriteEngine on
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: clicking on contact seems to work, maybe your htaccess was cached?

Comment: Try resetting your browser cache; it works fine for us. Take at look at this [link](http://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome) for help on that.

Comment: ye, seems like it was cached in my browser... thanks fixed it now